# Are limits in distribution unique?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Is the following true?
Suppose $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are sequences of (real-valued) random variables. 
Suppose that $X_n = Y_n$ in law. 
Suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ in law, and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in law. 
Then $X=Y$ in law.

How would you prove this?
Many thanks.

Comment: one way to show it is showing that $X$ and $Y$ have the same characteristic function (you need to know the result that characteristic function completely determines the law of a random variable)

Answer (score 1):

$F_{X_n}(x) \to F_X(x)$ for any $x$ at which $F_X$ is continuous. Similarly, $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_Y(x)$ for any $x$ at which $F_Y$ is continuous. Since a CDF can have at most countably many points of discontinuity, this means $F_X$ and $F_Y$ disagree on at most countably many points. I believe this forces $F_X$ and $F_Y$ to agree everywhere.